# Specific Sequence using Trigger & Sequence in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, sequence, database-trigger

I have a SQL Table for which I have written Triggers and Sequence which inserts 'I', 'U', 'D' in a column every time a record is inserted, deleted or updated.
I also needed a sequence every time a new record is inserted in the table so I used a sequence for that.

```
 CREATE TABLE "USER_DETAILS" 
   (  
  "ID" NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1), 
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
  "CONTACT" NUMBER(10,0),
  "STATUS" CHAR(1),
  SEQUENCE VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

My output is like this, the sequence number starts with A00001 as per the sequence I wrote.

```
ID  NAME     CONTACT  STATUS SEQUENCE

1   USER1   123456789   I     A00001
2   USER2   123456789   I     A00002
```

This is my trigger for "STATUS"

```
create or replace trigger insert_trigger before insert on USER_DETAILS for each row

begin
  insert into USER_DETAILS
    (ID,NAME,CONTACT,STATUS, SEQUENCE)
  values
    (:new.id,:new.name,:new.contact,'I',NULL);

end;
```

and this is my Sequence for the field "Sequence".

```
create or replace trigger insert_trigger before insert on USER_DETAILS for each row
begin
  :new.SEQUENCE := 'A'||to_char(REF_SEQUENCE.nextval,'FM00000');
 end;
```

But now the requirement is to start the sequence with the first alphabet of the field "Name".
For example: If the Name is **"User1"** then the sequence should be **"U00001"**
             ,if the Name is **"Random1"** then the sequence should be **"R00001"**

I don't know how to achieve his functionality. Help!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create sequence like the following by using `lpad` and `substr` string operators :

```
create or replace trigger insert_trigger before insert on USER_DETAILS for each row
begin
  :new.SEQUENCE := substr(:new.name,1,1)||lpad(to_char(REF_SEQUENCE.nextval),5,'0');
 end;
```

P.S. do not use deprecated data type `CHAR`, use `VARCHAR2` for all of your string type columns, instead.